# Excel - Close/Save using full path name

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Is there a way of inserting the full pathname instead of the filename when closing and saving a workbook

E.g below

```
Workbooks("BOOK1.XLS").Close SaveChanges:=true
Workbooks("C:\user\docs\BOOK1.XLS").Close SaveChanges:=true
```

Reason why I ask is that I've already named all my full pathnames in strings

```
Workbooks(i).Close SaveChanges:=true
```

So for each i in array etc

Comment: This line of code `Workbooks("C:\user\docs\BOOK1.XLS").Close SaveChanges:=true` is the answer to your question, so I'm not really sure what you're asking...

Comment: What happened when you tried it? Did it work or not?

Comment: @FreeMan I'm trying to use arrays in the vba e.g Workbooks(i).Close SaveChanges:=true this doesnt seem to work

Comment: Try `Workbooks.Close SaveChanges:=True`

Comment: How about showing the full code of what you've written instead of 3 random lines. Include the definition of your array, where you populate it, what you're attempting to do to save the files, what error you're getting and what line it's occurring on. That may help with the diagnosis.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Workbook object can be used like in your first statement

```
Workbooks("BOOK1.XLS").Close
```

because it uses the .Name property (without full path)

The `Workbooks.Open` method on the other hand, takes as parameter the full path and file name:

```
Workbooks.Open "C:\user\docs\BOOK1.XLS"
```

It can take the file name without a path as well, but it will search for it in the default folder

.

There are 2 options I use to solve similar problems, where all strings include full path and file name:

1. set a reference to the workbook when you open it:

   `Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\user\docs\BOOK1.XLS")`

   - then you can close it like this

     **`wb.Close SaveChanges:=True`**
2. Extract the file name from the string containing both, path and file name:

   `wbName = Mid(fullName, InStrRev(fullName, "\") + 1)`

   - then you can close it as in your first line:

     **`Workbooks(wbName).Close SaveChanges:=true`**